# Where's "More Info" gone?

Tags: audio, metadata, waveform

Recently I moved from 10.13 to 10.14 on an older Mac system. Previously, tapping on an audio file and keying "command + i" would tell me some audio info, such as stereo, channels, bit depth; now that section of the info box is blank. Is this normal?

Comment: Confirmed, checked same file on Mojave & El Cap. El Cap has the info, Mojave doesn't. Never noticed before.

Comment: hmm… also checked Big Sur - it's back again.

Comment: Ahh, that's the difference then. no Spotlight on the file location on Mojave.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I am not convinced this is a spotlight issue but it certainly points to it. I'm puzzled as to why the command + i has only stopped giving me the extra info at the 10.14 os upgrade.

Comment: I copied the same file to several different computers & disk locations. As soon as I copied from my un-indexed Downloads drive to the boot drive, I got the Info. The other computers here don't have any un-indexed drives, so i can't test that, only my main Mac, on Mojave.

Comment: I did the same, moving to external drive, and the 'info' returned. Although my Mac HD is indexed for Spotlight, it still does not give media metadata in the info box. Thank you for looking at it. would love to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Where's "More Info" gone?

In **macOS Mojave**, I just tested it with an **.m4a** and an **.mp3** *file*, residing on my **Desktop**, and the **More Info:** was there. Not just the *category* but actually *information* about the *file*.

**Note:** The *files* must reside on a *volume* that has been indexed by **Spotlight**.

Comment: AFAIK, The volume is indexed by spotlight. It's my internal mac hd. This system moved from 10.13 to 10.14 a couple of months ago. The command + i on music gave the more info details always, on this 2015 Mac book pro, so my suspicion is that spotlight is on. I could try 'resetting' spotlight over the weekend or next time the system is idle.

Comment: I've still got the issue. Would love a solution. I get no 'info' on audio on my Mac HD. If I drag audio to an external drive, I get the 'info'. I've dragged my Mac HD into the Spotlight privacy window and then removed it, as per Apple support, to try and redo/kickstart spotlight (if spotlight is the issue) but it has not solved this conundrum.

Comment: HD confirmed is indexed. The more info appears for video media, but not for audio.